# Positioning Issues with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, position

I'm working on a webpage that includes a few sections of content, an image slideshow, and a top fixed nav bar. My problem has to do with the layout of the slideshow. I have the slideshow set up to use absolute positioning, but it then sits on top of my other content. The only way I've been able to get the rest of my content to move lower on the page is to use absolute positioning with everything. If I try to use containers and use relative positioning, it moves my right/left selector arrows and clutters up the whole slideshow. Can anyone show me a better way to orient content this way along the page?

HTML

```html
<div id="doc">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="container">
      <img src="Images/Slideshow/img1.jpg" id="img" />
      <div id="leftHolder">
        <img onClick="slide(-1)" class="left" src="Images/arrowLeft.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="rightHolder">
        <img onClick="slide(+1)" class="left" src="Images/arrowRight.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
#doc {
  margin: 40px 0;
}
#content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1140px;
}
#container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin-top: 110px;
}
#leftHolder {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin-left: 65px;
}
#rightHolder {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.left {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0px;
}
.right {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  right: 0px;
}
#img {
  height: 600px;
  width: 1140px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: please show us some code :-)

Answer (score 2):

Absolute positioning (along with fixed) removes the element from the standard layout flow, which is why everything else is "shifting around and the only way to fix it is to absolutely position everything."

However, there is another solution.

Take the div that is currently absolutely positioned, wrap it in another div, and make that div relatively positioned.  You may have to enforce some width/height on it, but that will keep the flow.

Comment: I've actually been trying just that, however, even 2 levels of parenting still distorts my arrow selectors. Let me post some code, not looking for someone to give me the exact answer so much as to explain the mechanics of my positioning.

Comment: @vulgarknight Please put the code into an edit of your question, in the comments it is impossible to read.

Comment: Ok, sorry, still learning StackOverflow